# HTML5 localStorage Perform Action on Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

Following the tutorial here, http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/96-localstorage-for-forms/. I was able to recreate the functionality with the submit buttons, however, instead of the buttons, is it possible to use checkboxes instead?

Here's what I have so far,

```
if (localStorage) {

$(function() {

    // Insert new buttons
    $("#savelinks")
        .after("<input type='submit' value='Save Address' id='saveData'> &nbsp;&nbsp;")
        .after("<input type='submit' value='Clear Saved Address' id='clearData'>");

    $("#saveData")
        .click(function(e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    // Test if saved data exists on page load
                    localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
                    var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();

                    // iterate over results
                    $.each(data, function(i, obj) {

                                   localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);

                     });

        });



    if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {
        var data = $("#form1").serializeArray();
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            $("[name='" + obj.name +"']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
        });
    }   



    $("#clearData")
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem("flag", "");
        });
});
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, but why use checkboxes for saving and clearing data?

Comment: To have something like [] Save Address, whereby checking the box would save the address for future use, and unchecking it would clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event and see whether or not the checkbox is checked;

```
$('#MyCheckbox').change(function() {

  var $this = $(this), // Current checkbox
      isChecked = this.checked, // We can also use $this.prop('checked')
      data = $('#form1').serializeArray();

  if (isChecked) {
    // Store serialized form data
  } else {
    // Clear stored form data
  }

});
```